# Create space when I save js document in visualstudio code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, space

when I save the document, it automatically create space between html element tags

Eg.

```
<h1> after save < h1 />
```

[image: sample link]

Comment: I guess the reason is some kind of format you use. You can try turn off format on save feature in setting `"editor.formatOnSave": false`

Comment: This happens when the editor.formatOnSave user setting is enabled, but your formatter isn't configured correctly for the version of React you are in